# Report Error in ERPNEXT cloud base frapppoecloud

Tags: cloud, erpnext, frappe

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLYrD.png)
whenever i creat the report i found this error any one help me to resole this .. what is the issue !!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running:

```bash
bench migrate
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Frappe Cloud doesn't support development environments. In development environments, you may create query reports with Python code in your application level. In a production environment, changes like these (creating reports) are typically stored in the site level.

If you're seeing this error while creating a new (non custom) report, then this is most likely a bug. Without version information or access to installed apps & site, relying on Frappe Cloud support would be your best bet.